# I can't add/resize a partition with more than 36 GB - there is plenty of free space

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, big-sur, dual-boot

I wish to install Linux and shrink my existing volumes + add a new partition with 600 GB for Linux.

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         2.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            15.3 GB    disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 15.3 GB    disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     1.1 TB     disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume Preboot                 520.9 MB   disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume Recovery                622.1 MB   disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s5
```

The UI (Disk Utility) does not allow me to create more than 36 GB partition. I can't fill out the number.

free disk space not the issue:

[image]

current setup in UI:

[image]

add partition for Linux

[image]

not allowed to enter custom number bigger than 36 GB.

[image]

Comment: The free space isn't continuous, most likely.

Comment: The entire disk is taken up by the APFS container.  To do what you want, it would have to shrink the APFS container.  Apparently that's not possible, I couldn't say why for sure.  Aside... why do you want to install a pseudo-Linux to replace a real one?  Do a VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For create a 600g free space from the terminal, the command is

```
sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots /
```

or

```
tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999 4
```

then

```
diskutil ap resizecontainer disk1 1.4t
```